# Как динамически добавлять и удалять элементы массива jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть каталог моделей с возможностью выбора каждой модели кнопкой, при нажатии на кнопку в массив добавляется имя модели (div с именем находится в одном блоке с кнопкой), при повторном нажатии на кнопку имя должно удалиться из массива, подскажите как это сделать? Имена могут повторяться. На данный момент, получается только добавлять имена моделей в массив:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var models = [];
  $('.mc-block .mc-change-button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
      $(this).html('Выбрать модель');
      models.splice(models.indexOf($(this).parent().find('.model-name').html()), 1);
      alert(models);
    } else {
      $(this).html('Модель выбрана');
      models.push($(this).parent().find('.model-name').html());
      alert(models);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.mc-block {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.mc-change-button.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 05
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 04
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 02
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
```

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6k0k4f0y/

Comment: ищешь в массиве индекс нужного элемента, и используешь [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: @Grundy Если допустим имена повторяются то как искать?

Comment: А что у тебя в массиве хранится? если просто имена, то какая разница какое из одинаковых имен удалять?

Comment: @Grundy Логично. Ну а все-же, чтобы удалить именно имя модели на кнопку которой нажали, нужно в массив добавлять объект?

Comment: Это выглядит логично :-) но не видя что у тебя за объекты и минимального примера рабочего кода сейчас сложно сказать как лучше сделать. Добавь в вопрос сниппет чтобы его можно было запустить и представить как это сейчас происходит

Comment: "чтобы удалить ... нужно добавлять" ?

Comment: @Igor чтобы продать что-нибудь ненужное - нужно сначала купить что-нибудь ненужное

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, сравни по буквам какую функцию я указал, и какую ты использовал. Кроме этого стоит проверить, что данный элемент вообще есть в массиве, иначе indexOf вернет -1, и удалится последний элемент

Comment: @Grundy да, ошибся, ну он там по логике должен быть, его же туда сперва добавили

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, теперь непонятна суть вопроса :-) у тебя же есть рабочий сниппет, который и добавляет и удаляет значения

Comment: @Grundy изначально я думал что нужно удалить именно то имя на кнопку которого нажали. Но потом я понял, что это бред, какая разница какое из одинаковых имен в дальнейшем использовать

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вот такое странное решение, которое основано на создании цикла, который будет проверять все значения массива

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var models = [];
  $('.mc-block .mc-change-button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
      $(this).html('Выбрать модель');
      //----------//
      for (var i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (models[i] == $(this).parent().find('.model-name').text()) {
          models.splice(i, 1);
          break
        };
      };
      //----------//
    } else {
      $(this).html('Модель выбрана');
      models.push($(this).parent().find('.model-name').text());

    }
    alert(models);
  });
});
```

```css
.mc-block {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.mc-change-button.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
<div class="mc-block">
  <div class="model-name">
    Александра 01
  </div>
  <a class="mc-change-button">Выбрать модель</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Простите, что это за жесть с флагом `del`? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_break.asp

Comment: А в чем отличие от простого удаления? Предварительная поверка?

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, да

Comment: @Igor, боже! Как стыдно. Совсем позабыл об этом ._.

Comment: А чем этот код отличается от того, что в вопросе, за исключением того, что тут цикл вместо IndexOf?